# What can the ADD/OR in python be used for?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am curious about how to use  `add` and `or` in diverse way when I'm reading python2.7 document about [data structure](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-conditions).

Below is its example code:

```
>>> string1, string2, string3 = '', 'Trondheim', 'Hammer Dance'
>>> non_null = string1 or string2 or string3
>>> non_null
'Trondheim'
```

`and` and `or` is called short-circuit operation.Their arguments are evaluated from left to right, and evaluation stops as soon as the outcome is determined. But it returns the last evaluated argument.What can I use it for?I can do it using `for ... in`, `if` and other construction because in my opinion, the return value maybe not what I want using `add` or `or`.

Comment: Did you mean `and` instead of `add`?

Comment: Just remember that it is possible and one day you will find a use for it.

Comment: yes, `and`@user2357112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of the example you can use `or` to select the first non-empty string.

More broadly `or` will give you the first non-false, not-none, non-empty value.

Similarly `and` will give you the last of such elements.

I tend to use them most frequently with boolean values where they correspond to the logical operations of at least one oprand must be true (for `or`) and all oprands must be true (for `and`).